# Can't add Id attribute to html element with jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I tried to set `id` attribute to html element in `jinja2`:

```
{% for track in tracks %}
   <a class="d-flex justify-content-between" id="{{track.["id"]}}">{{ track.artists[0]["name"] + ' - ' + track["title"]}}
   </a>
{% endfor %}
```

And on block `id="{{track.["id"]}}"` got error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected name or number
```

What can i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a dot too much, try change

```
id="{{track.["id"]}}"
```

to:

```
id="{{track["id"]}}"
```